# Build spark schema from json schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to build a spark schema the want to explicity supply while creating the dataframe
I can generate the json schema using below

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
# Save schema from the original DataFrame into json:
schema_json = df.schema.json()
```

which gives me

```
{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"cloud_events_version","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"data","nullable":true,"type":{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"email","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"member_role","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"reg_source_product","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"school_type","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"year_in_college","nullable":true,"type":"long"}],"type":"struct"}},{"metadata":{},"name":"event_time","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"event_type","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"event_type_version","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"event_validated_ts","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"event_validation_status","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"extensions","nullable":true,"type":{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"client_common","nullable":true,"type":{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"adobe_mcid","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"adobe_sdid","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"auth_state","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"uuid","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"client_experiments","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"client_ip_address","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"device_id","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"page_name","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"referral_url","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"url","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"user_agent","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"uvn","nullable":true,"type":"string"}],"type":"struct"}}],"type":"struct"}},{"metadata":{},"name":"source","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"validated_message","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"year","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},{"metadata":{},"name":"mon","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},{"metadata":{},"name":"day","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},{"metadata":{},"name":"hour","nullable":true,"type":"integer"}],"type":"struct"}
```

But for this I need to parse the dataframe , which takes a bit of time and I am trying to avoid

One thing I can do is fetch the desired schema from a catalog that we have internally . 
Which gives something like

```
[{u'Name': u'cloud_events_version', u'Type': u'string'},
 {u'Name': u'event_type', u'Type': u'string'},
 {u'Name': u'event_time', u'Type': u'string'},
 {u'Name': u'data', u'Type': u'struct<school_type:string,reg_source_product:string,member_role:string,email:string,year_in_college:int>'},
 {u'Name': u'source', u'Type': u'string'},
 {u'Name': u'extensions', u'Type': u'struct<client_common:struct<auth_state:string,client_ip_address:string,client_experiments:string,uvn:string,device_id:string,adobe_sdid:string,url:string,page_name:string,user_agent:string,uuid:string,adobe_mcid:string,referral_url:string>>'},
 {u'Name': u'event_type_version', u'Type': u'string'},
 {u'Name': u'event_validation_status', u'Type': u'string'},
 {u'Name': u'event_validated_ts', u'Type': u'string'},
 {u'Name': u'validated_message', u'Type': u'string'}]
```

I am trying to write a recursive python query which generate the above json.
Logic is to loop through this list of dict and assign name and type to this dictionary , when the type is string

```
{"metadata" : {},"name" : columnName,"nullable" : True,"type" : columnType}
```

but when the type is struct then it creates a list of dictionary of all the element of struct and assign it to type and do it recursively until it does not find any struct.

All i can muster is

```
def structRecursive(columnName,columnType):
    if "struct" not in columnType:
        ColumnDict = {"metadata" : {},"name" : columnName,"nullable" : True,"type" : columnType}
    else:
        structColumnList = []
        structColumnDict = {
            'metadata': {},
            'name': columnName,
            'nullable': True,
            'type': {'fields': structColumnList, 'type': 'struct'}
        }
        if columnType.count('struct<')==1:
            structCol = columnName
            structColList = columnType.encode('utf-8').replace('struct<',
                    '').replace('>', '').split(',')
            for item in structColList:
                fieldName = item.split(':')[0]
                dataType = item.split(':')[1]
                nodeDict = {}
                nodeDict['metadata'] = {}
                nodeDict['name'] = '{}'.format(fieldName)
                nodeDict['nullable'] = True
                nodeDict['type'] = '{}'.format(dataType)
                structColumnList.append(nodeDict)
        else:
            columnName = columnType.replace('struct<','',1).replace('>','').split(':')[0]
            columnType = columnType.split("{}:".format(columnName),1)[1].replace('>','',1)
        return structColumnDict

MainStructList = []
MainStructDict = {'fields': MainStructList, 'type': 'struct'}
for item in ListOfDict :
    columnName = item['Name'].encode('utf-8')
    columnType = item['Type'].encode('utf-8')
    MainStructList.append(structRecursive(columnName,columnType))
```

Ofcourse this is not giving the desired result.
Would love to get some suggestion here .

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question right, you would like to parse the list of columns and convert it into a dictionary describing the schema with the complex types as well. The hard part is parsing the string representing the complex types. First we need a method that extracts the struct entries from a column definition:

```
def extract_struct(text):
    stop = 7
    flag = 1
    for c in text[7:]:
        stop += 1
        if c == "<":
            flag += 1
        if c == ">":
            flag -= 1
        if flag == 0:
            return text[:stop], text[stop:]
```

This will return you the extracted struct and the remaining text from the column definition. For example

```
extract_struct("struct<a:int,b:double>,c:string")
```

will return

```
("struct<a:int,d:double>", "c:string").
```

Second, we need to walk through each column type and get the definition of the struct entries:

```
def parse(s, node):
    while s != '':
        # Strip column name
        col_name = s.partition(':')[0]
        s = s.partition(':')[2]

        # If column type is struct, parse it as well
        if s.startswith('struct'):
            col_type, s = extract_struct(s)
            node[col_name] = {}
            parse(col_type[7:-1], node[col_name])
        else:
            # Just add column definition
            col_type = s.partition(',')[0]
            node[col_name] = {
                "metadata": {},
                "name": col_name,
                "nullable": True,
                "type": col_type
            }

        # Go to next entry
        s = s.partition(',')[2]
```

The above method simply adds a new column to the current node in the schema tree if the column type is simple, otherwise it extracts the name and struct and recursively goes through the struct's children entries. Now we only have to go through each column and parse them. So after wrapping up the above in one method:

```
def build(columns):
    def extract_struct(text):
        stop = 7
        flag = 1
        for c in text[7:]:
            stop += 1
            if c == '<':
                flag += 1
            if c == '>':
                flag -= 1
            if flag == 0:
                return text[:stop], text[stop:]

    def parse(s, node):
        while s != '':
            # Strip column name
            col_name = s.partition(':')[0]
            s = s.partition(':')[2]

            # If column type is struct, parse it as well
            if s.startswith('struct'):
                col_type, s = extract_struct(s)
                node[col_name] = {}
                parse(col_type[7:-1], node[col_name])
            else:
                # Just add column definition
                col_type = s.partition(',')[0]
                node[col_name] = {
                    "metadata": {},
                    "name": col_name,
                    "nullable": True,
                    "type": col_type
                }

            # Go to next entry
            s = s.partition(',')[2]

    schema = {}
    for column in columns:
        parse("{}:{}".format(column['Name'], column['Type']), schema)
    return schema
```

Now if you run it on your example list, you get the following dictionary (which is easy to convert into a list of columns, but the order doesn't really matter anyway):

```
{
  "cloud_events_version": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "cloud_events_version", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "event_type": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "event_type", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "event_time": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "event_time", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "event_validated_ts": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "event_validated_ts", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "event_type_version": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "event_type_version", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "source": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "source", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "extensions": {
    "client_common": {
      "adobe_sdid": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "adobe_sdid", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "auth_state": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "auth_state", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "client_ip_address": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "client_ip_address", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "url": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "url", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "client_experiments": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "client_experiments", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "referral_url": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "referral_url", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "page_name": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "page_name", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "user_agent": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "user_agent", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "uvn": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "uvn", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "chegg_uuid": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "chegg_uuid", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "adobe_mcid": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "adobe_mcid", 
        "metadata": {}
      }, 
      "device_id": {
        "nullable": true, 
        "type": "string", 
        "name": "device_id", 
        "metadata": {}
      }
    }
  }, 
  "validated_message": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "validated_message", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "event_validation_status": {
    "nullable": true, 
    "type": "string", 
    "name": "event_validation_status", 
    "metadata": {}
  }, 
  "data": {
    "school_type": {
      "nullable": true, 
      "type": "string", 
      "name": "school_type", 
      "metadata": {}
    }, 
    "reg_source_product": {
      "nullable": true, 
      "type": "string", 
      "name": "reg_source_product", 
      "metadata": {}
    }, 
    "member_role": {
      "nullable": true, 
      "type": "string", 
      "name": "member_role", 
      "metadata": {}
    }, 
    "email": {
      "nullable": true, 
      "type": "string", 
      "name": "email", 
      "metadata": {}
    }, 
    "year_in_college": {
      "nullable": true, 
      "type": "int", 
      "name": "year_in_college", 
      "metadata": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, note that this only works for simple types and `struct` (not for `array` or `map` types). But it's fairly easy to extend to other complex types as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use standard json-schema https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/about.html and use this json-shema to convert to spark schema https://github.com/zalando-incubator/spark-json-schema#quickstart

Answer (score -3):

Was able to solve this finally

```
def struct_definition(column_name, column_type):
    column_dict = {"metadata": {}, "name": column_name, "nullable": True, "type": column_type}
    return column_dict


def convert_to_json_array(struct_def):
    striped = struct_def.lstrip('struct')
    striped = striped.lstrip('<')
    striped = striped.rstrip('>')
    main_struct_list = []
    if striped.__contains__('struct'):
        name = striped.split(':')[0]
        json = {'Name': name, 'Type': striped.lstrip(name + ':') + '>'}
        main_struct_list.append(json)
    else:
        for i in striped.split(','):
            key_value = i.split(':')
            normalized_json = {'Name': key_value[0], 'Type': key_value[1]}
            main_struct_list.append(normalized_json)
    return main_struct_list


def to_json(input_list):
    main_struct_list = []
    for x in input_list:
        column_name = x['Name']
        column_type = x['Type']
        if column_type.startswith('struct'):
            main_struct_list.append(
                struct_definition(column_name,
                                  {'fields': to_json(convert_to_json_array(column_type)), 'type': 'struct'}))
        else:
            main_struct_list.append(struct_definition(column_name, column_type))
    return main_struct_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_list = [{u'Name': u'cloud_events_version', u'Type': u'string'},
                   {u'Name': u'event_type', u'Type': u'string'},
                   {u'Name': u'event_time', u'Type': u'string'},
                   {u'Name': u'data',
                    u'Type': u'struct<school_type:string,reg_source_product:string,member_role:string,email:string,year_in_college:int>'},
                   {u'Name': u'source', u'Type': u'string'},
                   {u'Name': u'extensions',
                    u'Type': u'struct<client_common:struct<auth_state:string,client_ip_address:string,client_experiments:string,uvn:string,device_id:string,adobe_sdid:string,url:string,page_name:string,user_agent:string,uuid:string,adobe_mcid:string,referral_url:string>>'},
                   {u'Name': u'event_type_version', u'Type': u'string'},
                   {u'Name': u'event_validation_status', u'Type': u'string'},
                   {u'Name': u'event_validated_ts', u'Type': u'string'},
                   {u'Name': u'validated_message', u'Type': u'string'}]
    main_struct_dict = {'fields': to_json(sample_list), 'type': 'struct'}
    print(main_struct_dict)
```

Comment: would be better to join the code with an explanation of what you are doing.